# How to programmatically execute WHEN and THEN on MySQL update using Python and Django?

Tags: python, mysql, django

I would like to update multiple rows in one single query by using UPDATE CASE scenario in mySQL.
I am building my web app using python and Django.  Here is my code:

```
UPDATE order
SET priority_number =
    CASE priority_number
    WHEN 2 THEN 3  
    WHEN 3 THEN 4
    WHEN 1 THEN 5
    WHEN 4 THEN 2
    WHEN 5 THEN 1
END
```

So this single query will update all field as I desire. My question is, how can I program this if I have an unknown number of rows to update? Lets say all these numbers comes from an array that I will pass into my views and I don’t know how many WHEN and THEN statement I need to write? thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically build up a query, using the conditionals [`Case`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#case) and [`When`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#when).

So, for example:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

# Make a list of When expressions
when_list = [When(priority_number=2, then=3),
             When(priority_number=3, then=4)]

# Use in a query of your choice, as an example:
Model.objects.update(
    priority_number=Case(
        *when_list))
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the respond! where can I pass my array here?

Comment: OP search the solution for `update` not for `select`

Comment: Updated the answer to include a list.

Comment: Hi, I created a lists of WHEN as you mentioned. But when I pass it as *when_list into the Case (per your example) it is literally trying to execute *when_list and not whats in that lists. Any advise?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to import. Let me try again!