# How to update multiple rows in MySQL (CASE, WHEN, THEN) using python/Django

Tags: python, mysql, django

I asked this question yesterday but It didn’t really help me. I am asking it again hoping my question is more clear this time. I am trying to update multiple rows in MySQL by using WHEN, THEN, ELSE case. I am trying to achieve this using python and Django in the backend. Here is my code:

```
UPDATE priority
SET priority_order =
    CASE priority_order
    WHEN 4 THEN 8
    WHEN 1 THEN 4
    WHEN 3 THEN 2

         ## More X amount of WHEN/THEN statements 

    ELSE priority_order
END
```

The problem is that I do not know how many WHEN and THEN lines I have.. How can I construct such a statement so that I can execute this using cursor.execute( )?

Yesterday, someone advised to build a list of expression and pass as an argument like:

```
from django.db.models import Case, When

# Make a list of When expressions
when_list = [When(priority_number=2, then=3),
             When(priority_number=3, then=4)]

# Use in a query of your choice, as an example:
Model.objects.update(
    priority_number=Case(
        *when_list))
```

But seems like it does not work on Mysql. I think this only works on SQLLite. The *when_list is not being decoded as my query execute. Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically execute WHEN and THEN on MySQL update using Python and Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353387/how-to-programmatically-execute-when-and-then-on-mysql-update-using-python-and-d)

Comment: Hi this was my question as well. I

Answer (score 0):

Can you try it:

```
when_data = [(2, 3), (3, 4), ] # Your method for generate the data
when_list = [When(priority_number=a, then=b) for a, b in when_data]
default = 90000 # Your value here

# Change YourModel
qs = YourModel.objects.update(priority_number=Case(
        *when_list,
         default=default
    ))
 # Now you can look on sql string
 from django.db import connection
 print (connection.queries[-1])
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the comment. I get an error of ""You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*when_list,\n                    default=default\n"

Comment: I am using mysql to execute the update. So instead of Models.objects.update()  I am using cursor.execute(""" .... then code """) May I ask what is the correct syntax in mysql?

Comment: do you have a model, why are you use cursor?

Comment: I have a model. But I am connected to mysql for my database.

Comment: updated the answer, you can look for syntax if need, but i don understand why you can not to use django methods.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. qs returns as 0. qs.query returns as an error.

Comment: sorry for `update` query method need use connection.queries i update the answer